# lock/freeze face set?

Tags: sculpting, masking, sculpt

I know I can click H while hovering over a face set, if I want to only sculpt that.

But what if I need to see the other objects in order to place my sculpting correctly?

There must be a way to lock or freeze a selection of face sets, so I only sculpt on the face sets of my choice.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try auto-masking by Face-sets option:

[image]